# EF Core initiate model object without required value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a model with some properties, one of which is a `User`:

```
public int UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public UserProfileModel User { get; set; }
```

And I have some JSON I'm posting up from the browser to a controller action:

```
[HttpPost("Add")]
public IActionResult Add(MyModel data) //<-- can't get this populated
{
    MyModel model = _service.Add(data);
    return Ok(model);
}
```

It works great! Except... it immediately errors out, because `User` is a required field. I am passing the `UserId` up. If I remove the `User` field from the model it works.

For context, this is part of a larger application framework with this sort of pattern.

I know I could create a separate Data Transfer Object and map it over to the original `Model` but that is a lot of extra code and manual configuration for this scenario.

Is there a way to get the Controller action and/or EF Core to somehow instantiate the object and just not be concerned with the User property?

Am I way overthinking this and I should just make `User` nullable, keeping `UserId` as the required field?

---

Example payload:

```
{
  "title": "Test",
  "content": "Lorem Ipsum Etc",
  "userId": 1,
  "comments": [],
  "topicsIds": [
    29,
    30
  ],
  "topics": []
}
```

Comment: A 'ViewModel' is not and should not be a 'entity model'.  Just because they (currently) contain similar properties does not mean they are the same thing.  Can you post the JSON?

Comment: @Neil normally sure, I agree with you, but in this case I have a pattern where these 'view models' are going to be exactly the 'entity model', 1:1, every time. Added payload example

Comment: I think you can just put:

public UserProfileModel User { get; set; } = new(); <-- to initialize it

This will depend of your c# version.

Comment: If you instantiate this `User` property with real user data and pass it back to view, you will get a full User model on your frontend(with password, etc.) which may lead to a leak of a confidential data.

Comment: @Serhii yes, but I have rules and configurations to handle data exposure so that never happens

Comment: @CristinaCarrasco Actually this is wrong - one should never initialize reference navigation property with `new`, as this breaks EF entity loading related data (eager, explicit or lazy) process. Serialization/binding problems cannot be solved by techniques breaking entity data model rules.

Comment: @IvanStoev you appear to be correct. At this point I've simply ensured that any of the reference navigation properties are nullable, while maintaining explicit FK properties that are not. This allows me to pass the desired FK id, and basic validation still picks up on the FK not being assigned when it's needed. Not entirely ideal but it works